# TopoGeometry commands with postgres are really slow

Tags: postgresql, postgis-2.0, topology, topojson

After messing around quite a while, I was finally able to get a topogeometry converted from my geometry table following the example of [toTopoGeom](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.1/toTopoGeom.html). I have the topology extension, with a topology schema ([SRID = 5367](https://epsg.io/5367)) and a table in the public schema with a topogeometry column.

However, after running a couple of minutes I quit the query because it would take too long. Now I have around 4000 rows in the topogeometry table and only ~10% converted.

Then I wanted to convert the topogeometry to a topojson following the example of the [AsTopoJSON](http://postgis.net/docs/AsTopoJSON.html). It works ok, but it takes 7 seconds to generate 4000 rows, which is really slow in my opinion.

So the question is; is this a common problem and is there an alternative approach to speed things up?

**used code**

1. Insert topogeometry from geometry:

   ```
   INSERT INTO grid_topo(topo)
   SELECT topology.toTopoGeom(geom, 'grid_topo', 1)
   FROM grid
   WHERE gid >= 0 AND id < 500;
   ```

(added the condition to limit the running time).

2. Generate TopoJSON from topogeometry:

   ```
   SELECT AsTopoJSON(topo, null) from grid_topo
   ```

Comment: It might help to see the query you're using and to know what coordinate system your geometries are stored in. For example, whether your table geometries are stored in a geographic or a cartesian coordinate system _might_ make a difference.

Comment: Also--it might help to disable [`AutoVaccuum`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/runtime-config-autovacuum.html) while you execute the query.

Comment: Using `ALTER TABLE grid_topo SET (
  autovacuum_enabled = true, toast.autovacuum_enabled = true
);`

Comment: During inserting data: With auto-vacuum = true it takes 24 seconds for 1000 rows/ With auto-vacuum = false it takes 22 seconds for 1000 rows. For generating topojson's it is not relevant if both vacuum is true or false; it takes 1.6s for 1000 rows